# SharePoint sharing files on local existing file systems

Tags: sharepoint-online, file, quota

Hi I want to share quite large-sized files on SharePoint but the quota space is too limited. I was wondering is there any method or free 3rd party tools that allows the mapping of files in Shared Documents to my local hard drive, bypassing the quota limit. In fact I found one http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-file-share-library.aspx which may provide the features I need but the license fee is quite hefty.

Comment: Can you advise what version of SharePoint you are using please?  2007 / 2010 / 2013

Comment: He tagged it SharePoint Online... not sure, but I think that's your answer.

Comment: Quite right. I didn't see that.

Comment: FWIW - I don't think Bamboo is supported in SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly leverage a page viewer web part and point it to the local file system. This might be a bit problematic with Sharepoint Online though. On premise it wouldn't be an issue.